# Counting number of characters in loaded file in textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, text-editor, counting

I can count number of characters when I'm typing in textarea

```js
function count_up(obj){
  document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = obj.value.length;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="textField" class="text_edit" id="my_text"  onkeyup="count_up(this);"></textarea><br/>
<span id="numbers">0</span>
```

but I want to count number of characters in file when I load it to textarea. This function is ok, but I must add something to loaded text if I want to count characters in my file(it's 
unintuitive). Can I do something to fix it?

Comment: "when I load it to textarea", you mean when loading in a file upload?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking ... _“when I load it to textarea”_ – and how exactly are you doing that? If you don’t mean an actual “upload”, but mere copy&paste, then you should look into more appropriate event handlers, such as `change` or `input`.

Comment: Yeah, I upload file with input. When I upload a file the number of characters is 0, but if I add something with keyboard (even one character) the number of characters is good. Do u understand what I mean?

Answer (score 2):

```css
textarea {
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        font-size: 16px;
        resize: none;
    }
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"  onkeyup="countCharToMax(this)"></textarea>
        <div id="charNum">0/30</div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function countCharToMax(val) {
            var max = 30;
            var min = 0;
            var len = val.value.length;
            if (len >= max) {
                val.value = val.value.substring(min, max);
                $('#charNum').text(len + '/'+max);
            } else {
                $('#charNum').text(len + '/'+max);
        
            }
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for count the characters on keyup event .

```
  function count_up(obj) {
    var len = obj.value.length;
    $("span#numbers").text(len);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using promise. Something like:

```
function loadFile() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try{
        //Function about loading file
        //...
        resolve(obj);
    } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
    }
  });
};
```

Then you should be able to get the count by using following:

```
loadFile()  //Will do count_up after the text is loaded
    .then(function(obj){ 
         count_up(obj);
     })
    .catch((reason) => {
         console.log('Handle rejected promise ('+reason+') here.');
     });
```